# Dead link in the website

Tags: security, web

My website is showing a **deadlink** and throwing an error to browser.

The requested URL /app/favicon.ico was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.12 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at www.somewebsitename.com Port 80

Can any malicious user exploit it and cause harm? And how?

Comment: get on /app/favicon.ico is usually silently made by the browser to add an icon to the page tab it's loading, technically is not a deadlink. just add an icon named favicon in your app directory to get rid of the 404. The page should load properly thou.

Answer (score 0):

Why show a dead link on the website? best limiting the error messages instead of showing them this information about the server try show them a generic error pages "oops somethings gone wrong"